# Error: No formulae or casks found for calicoctl

Tags: homebrew

I am tried to install calicoctl followed by https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/calicoctl in macOS 13.4 like this (M1 chip), but failed with this information:

```
> brew install calicoctl
fatal: not in a git directory
Warning: No remote 'origin' in /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services, skipping update!
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
No changes to formulae.

Warning: No available formula with the name "calicoctl".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
Error: No formulae or casks found for calicoctl.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: DId you run `brew doctor`? Or is this yet another issue caused by the chinese firewall?